# shell script, for loop, ssh and alias

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm trying to do something like this, I need to take backup from 4 blades, and
all should be stored under the `/home/backup/esa` location, which contains 4
directories with the name of the nodes (like sc-1, sc-2, pl-1, pl-2). Each
directory should contain respective node's backup information.

But I see that "from which node I execute the command, only that data is being
copied to all 4 directories". any idea why this happens? My script is like this:

```
for node in $(grep "^node" /cluster/etc/cluster.conf | awk '{print $4}');
do echo "Creating backup fornode ${node}";
ssh $node source /etc/profile.d/bkUp.sh;
asBackup -b /home/backup/esa/${node};
done
```

Comment: Please double-check that I edited your script correctly. Punctuation matters a lot, and I guessed some where `"` marks should go.

Comment: Why do you source `/etc/profile.d/bkUp.sh`?

Comment: @AaronDigulla: bkUp.sh contains an alias for asBackup command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is this piece of the code:

```
ssh $node source /etc/profile.d/bkUp.sh;
asBackup -b /home/backup/esa/${node};
```

It does:

1. Create a remote shell on `$node`
2. Execute the command `source /etc/profile.d/bkUp.sh` in the remote shell
3. Close the remote shell **and forget about anything done in that shell!!**
4. Run `asBackup` on the local host.

This is not what you want. Change it to:

```
ssh "$node" "source /etc/profile.d/bkUp.sh; asBackup -b '/home/backup/esa/${node}'"
```

This does:

1. Create a remote shell on `$node`
2. Execute the command(s) `source /etc/profile.d/bkUp.sh; asBackup -b '/home/backup/esa/${node}'` on the *remote* host

Make sure that `/home/backup/esa/${node}` is a NFS mount (otherwise, the files will only be backed up in a directory on the **remote** host).

Note that `/etc/profile` is a very bad place for backup scripts (or their config). Consider moving the setup/config to `/home/backup/esa` which is (or should be) shared between all nodes of the cluster, so changing it in one place updates it everywhere at once.

Also note the usage of quotes: The single and double quotes make sure that spaces in the variable `node` won't cause unexpected problems. Sure, it's very unlikely that there will be spaces in "$node" but if there are, the error message will mislead you.

So always quote properly.

Comment: No it still dont work, i tried the same command, but still esaBackup command not found error im getting!!!!  "bash: asaBackup: command not found"

Comment: What is **asa**Backup? Note that the executable search path may be reduced when running remote shells. If in doubt, call the command with an absolute path.

Comment: Sorry it is esaBackup, But the problem is i cant use absolute path!!! I have to do a source... From last two days its eating my head...

Comment: Set a variable in `bkUp.sh` which contains the path (say `BACKUP_HOME`) and then call it with `"$BACKUP_HOME/esaBackup"` or make sure `$BACKUP_HOME` is in `PATH`.

Answer (score 1):

The formatting of your question is a bit confusing, but it looks as if you have a quoting problem.  If you do

```
ssh $node source /etc/profile.d/bkUp.sh; esaBackup -b /home/backup/esa/${node}
```

then the command `source` is executed on `$node`. After the command finishes, the remote connection is closed and with it, the shell that contains the result of sourcing  `/etc/profile.d/bkUp.sh`. Now `esaBackup` command is run on the local machine. It won't see anything that you keep in `bkUp.sh

What you need to do is put quotes around all the commands you want the remote shell to run -- something like

```
ssh $node "source /etc/profile.d/bkUp.sh; esaBackup -b /home/backup/esa/${node}"
```

That will make ssh run the full list of commands on the remote node.

Comment: It doesn't work, now the error "esaBackup: command not found" ... Any help please @Roland

Comment: well, what command do you want to run remotely via ssh?  your question was hard to read, maybe I mistyped the command name.

Comment: @user1081026: It's always a good idea to use the full path to asBackup

Comment: #!/bin/bash
 for node in $(grep "^node" /cluster/etc/cluster.conf | awk '{print $4}');
        do echo "Creating ESA backup for node ${node}";
           ssh  $node "source /etc/profile.d/esa.sh; esaBackup -b /home/backup/esa/${node};"
        done;
After executing this script i'm getting error                          Creating ESA backup for node sc-1 bash: esaBackup: command not found                                   Creating ESA backup for node sc-2 bash: esaBackup: command not found 
@Roland

Comment: i tried to give full path for asBackup, i get now different error.      Creating ESA backup for node sc-1
[error] The environment variable "ESAHOMEINSTALL" cannot be determined.
Creating ESA backup for node sc-2
[error] The environment variable "ESAHOMEINSTALL" cannot be determined.
Creating ESA backup for node pl-1
[error] The environment variable "ESAHOMEINSTALL" cannot be determined.
Creating ESA backup for node pl-2
[error] The environment variable "ESAHOMEINSTALL" cannot be determined.
@PauloScardine

Comment: When using ssh to fire a remote command you may not be getting a full blown login session, probably your .login, .profile, .bash_rc, etc, are not being executed. You may need to set some environment variables.

Comment: @user1081026: Sounds like you've got most of the way there.  Does /etc/profile.d/esa.sh set the ESAHOMEINSTALL variable?  If not can you see which .login, .profile etc file does and alter esa.sh to include it.

Comment: esa.sh doesn't have any env. variable set. @Grhm

Comment: @Grhm: i do see ESAHOMEINSTALL  is being defined in /etc/profile. Now where else it should be defined??

Comment: @Grhm: wow it worked, it was defined in profile, and i just added the ESAHOMEINSTALL in esa.sh. Thanks

Comment: @Grhm: Now i'm facing one more problem, after doing ssh and executing the command, it says that the aliased command "bash: esaBackup command not found"??

Comment: @PauloScardine: Now i'm facing one more problem, after doing ssh and executing the command, it says that the aliased command "bash: esaBackup command not found"??

Comment: @user1081026: seems like an alias defined to an nonexistent destination, please look at the output of the "alias" command at the remote host - check if the alias is correctly defined.

Comment: @PauloScardine: I have defined all aliases properly.Only problem is with ssh and doing source.. please need some help...